# Expressions with slashes are highlighted incorrectly

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

First off: I'm not talking about multi line commenting, I don't think. The problem is occurring when there is a space between the / and the * such as

```
draw.arc(x, y, radius, Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2, true);
```

In dreamweaver, the text

```
/2,Math.PI/
```

Goes green.

I've googled but to no avail. I'm sure it's something dumb but I'm stumped.

Also note: still occurs when the Math.PI formula is defined as a variable

Comment: Why (Math.PI/180)*180 and not just Math.PI ?

Comment: Was just an example - the actual code was Math.PI/2 - edited initial question for clarity

Comment: I'm failing to see how this is a JavaScript question. It seems like a text editor problem. Does it even belong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dreamweaver is interpreting that as a regex for syntax highlighting.

The regex notation `/regex/` is the most notoriously difficult part to parse in all of Javascript.

Your code is fine. You could try adding spaces around the /. I've often seen that work.

Comment: Separate the parameters so they're on separate lines, maybe?

Comment: I like @JoeSimmons's suggestion. Try that.

Answer (score 2):

As stated below, it's a parsing issue with Dreamweaver - interpreting your syntax as a regular expression.

A solution to this problem would be to create a variable for that value. Additionally, it's more efficient than doing the same operation more than once.

```
var piOver2 = Math.PI / 2;

draw.arc(x, y, radius, piOver2, piOver2, true);
```

Comment: no luck with defining it as variable, also tried declaring as Number

Answer (score 1):

It is something dumb: Dreamweaver has a bug in it. Your code must still execute. That is a perfectly valid sequence of characters, that does not result in a comment.