# Uncaught SyntaxError : Unexpected token ;

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` at  `THE LINE NUMBER`

```
    // HTML Helper
    var documentHtml = function(html){
        // Prepare
        var result = String(html)
            .replace(/<!DOCTYPE[^>]*>/i, '')
            .replace(/<(html|head|body|title|meta|script)([s>])/gi,'<div class="document-$1"$2')
            .replace(/</(html|head|body|title|meta|script)>/gi,'</div>')
        ;  // << THE LINE NUMBER 
        // Return
        return $.trim(result);
    };
```

Not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is:

```
/</(html|head|body|title|meta|script)>/gi
```

At the time of writing, SO's highlighting shows the problem with the original: the regex seems to be `/</`.

It should be:

```
/<\/(html|head|body|title|meta|script)>/gi
```

Since Javascript uses forward slashes to delimit regexes, you have to escape any forward slash inside it with a backslash.

---

IMO, using forward slashes for regexes was the most unfortunate syntax decision of JavaScript:

1. Parsing JavaScript is difficult because of `/` starting multiline comments, single line comments, division, and regexes. (Sublime, my editor choice, gets it wrong. [Dreamweaver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750685/expressions-with-slashes-are-highlighted-incorrectly) gets it wrong.)
2. It makes regexes for URIs/URLs particularly ugly.

Comment: Well, I think it was a really great syntax decision. =) It’s inconvenient for parsing URLs and HTML – two things that should never really be parsed with regular expressions.

Comment: @minitech, what about matching URL paths, e.g. `/^\/some\/path\/prefix\/.*/.test(path)` (which I believe is what the OP is doing). What's wrong with that?

Comment: That looks like URL paths to you? `/<(html|head|body|title|meta|script)>/`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change:

```
.replace(/</(html|head|body|title|meta|script)>/gi,'</div>')
```

to:

```
.replace(/<\/(html|head|body|title|meta|script)>/gi,'<\/div>')
```

You need to escape `/` with `\` in Javascript